woocomerce: modal no se cierra (html,css y js)
Estoy intentando poner un botón para que cuando se presione se abra un modal preguntando si está seguro de agregar, pero no se cierra mi modal, no le cambia la clase, ademas que dispara el evento btnAddCard.click(); sin ni siquiera darle a Entendido.
O sea, al abrir el modal se dispara el evento. De antemano, gracias.

function botonpersonalizado() {
?>

    <button id="btnPersonalizado">ABRIR MODAL</button>

    <div id="popup-carrito" class="popup-hidden">
        <div id="popup-contenido">
            <p>¿Seguro que deseas añadir este producto al carrito?</p>
            <button id="btn-descartar">Cancelar</button>
            <button id="btn-entendido">Entendido</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
            const btnAddCard = document.querySelector('.single_add_to_cart_button');
            const btnModal = document.querySelector('#btnPersonalizado');
            const popup = document.querySelector('#popup-carrito');
            const btnCancelar = document.querySelector('#btn-descartar');
            const btnAgregar = document.querySelector('#btn-entendido');

            function mostrarModal(event) {
                event.preventDefault(); 
                event.stopPropagation();
                popup.classList.remove('popup-hidden'); 
                console.log('se presiono mostrar modal');
            };
  
            function ocultarModal(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                popup.classList.add('popup-hidden'); 
                console.log('se presiono cancelar');
            };
 
            function agregarCarrito(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                
                btnAddCard.click();
                console.log('se presiono entendido');
                ocultarModal(event);
            };

            if (btnModal) {
                btnModal.addEventListener('click', mostrarModal);
            };
            if (btnCancelar) {
                btnCancelar.addEventListener('click', ocultarModal);
            };
            if (btnAgregar) {
                btnAgregar.addEventListener('click', agregarCarrito);
            };
        });
    </script>
<?php
}
add_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'botonpersonalizado', 10);

